# Resize dynamically a table as another in VBA after Connection.Refresh- excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with Excel 2007, I have two tables in the same WorkSheet, let's say *tab1* and *tab2*. *tab1* is populated through a connection to a MS-SQL server and *tab2* contains some formulas referred to some cells of *tab1*, I use it for create some values useful for graphs and other stuff. The problem is that *tab1* changes it's number of rows every time i refresh the data connection, and i wish *tab2* to reflect this changes.
I tried to declare the range of *tab2* using an `OFFSET` function with references to *tab1*, this works during the declaration but when the *tab1* changes, *tab2* don't...so i think that the range specified in the declaration of the table couldn't change dynamically.
Since i refresh the data of the connection that populates *tab1* through VBA i tryed to resize the *tab2* using VBA. I do something like this:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("conn_name")
   .OLEDBConnection.CommandText = query 'query previously set
   .Refresh
End With
range_calculated = ....
' MsgBox range_calculated
With ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets(name_sheet)
   .ListObjects(name_table_to_refresh).Resize Range(range_calculated)
End With
```

For find the last row of *tab2* i used something like this:

```
last_row_tab2 = .ListObjects("tab1").range.Rows.Count + .ListObjects("tab1").range.Row - 1
```

and for the first and last column and first row i used something similar.

Now, the *Connection.Refresh* works because the *tab1* changes it's values and everything works properly (the table changes it's number of rows), but when I do the `Resize` method it doesn't work as expected. I put a `MsgBox` for catch the range calcouled and what I noticed is that looks like that or the `Refresh` method or the "refresh" of the *tab1* with the new data imported it's performed at the end of the Sub, not when i fire the `Refresh` in the code. I suspect this because the range shown in the *MsgBox* it's always the previous of the `Refresh`, so the one that reflects the actual size of the *tab1* before the `Refresh`. For example if now *tab1* ends at row 10 and i fire the macro, the *MsgBox* show me 10, but after the refresh the table ends to row 15; if i fire the macro again the *MsgBox* show me 15 but after the refresh the table ends to row 12...and so on.
What am i missing?
This is the only way i figured for resize the *tab2* accordingly *tab1*.

**Edit:**
I've also tryed to put the `Resize` part in another Sub and call this sub after the `Refresh`, but no changes.

Any help appreciated

Ettore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the issue and whant to share the solution.
In fact the `Refresh` was not performed when fired in the VBA code but later, and this because the option **Enable background refresh** of the connection i was refreshing was enabled. Disable this option permits to the VBA code to execute the query imediatly (from [Office support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connection-properties-c84c77c3-f2ac-4356-b4d7-88cd9a483c7a)):

> Enable background refresh    Select this check box to run the query in the background. Clear this check box to run the query while you wait. Running a query in the background enables you to use Excel while the query runs.

So, disable the option solved the problem.